# Can desktop sessions be used to save and restore shell buffers?

Tags: shell, desktop

Is it possible to use `desktop-save-mode` to save and partially restore my shell buffers? I realize shell buffers have quite a bit of state that isn't under the direct control of emacs, so specifically I am just looking to restore shell buffers with the shell running in whatever directory it was saved in. Not looking to restore prior output, env vars, or anything like that.

Comment: I do not know if there is any built-in support to restore the shell buffers; however, there is built-in support for the ability to create a custom solution if one does not already exist.  See the variable `desktop-buffer-mode-handlers` -- type `C-h v` aka `M-x describe-variable` to read the doc-string.  To set the working directory in shell, you can let-bind the `default-directory` when calling `shell` / `eshell` / `term` / etc.